# get full path using openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net

Simple utility to get a file for use.

Using openfiledialog I am trying to get the full path EG: File = text1.txt and it is located in c:\temp. So the full path is C:\temp\text1.txt.

But all I can get is the file name. I've searched I've hunted, I'e tried for a couple of hours and nothing works.

Here is code with comments...

```
'open the openfile dialog so the user can search for a file
        Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        'set the root to the z drive
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Z:\"
        'make sure the root goes back to where the user started
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        'show the dialog
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        'check there is something to work with... the user did not exit before selecting a file etc.
        If openFileDialog1.FileName.Length = 0 Then

            'if the user selected a file set the value of the replacefile text box
        Else
            TB_ReplacementFile.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)

        End If
```

All I get is the file name...

Comment: from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.100).aspx): `The file name includes both the file path and the extension.`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying... If I select a  file named text1.txt, the value returned is text1.txt, not filepath + text1.txt. Are you saying I am getting what I should and don't understand that? I have found dozens of posts asking the exact same question and saying "... do it like this..." and I am already doing that without success.

Comment: How do you know you just get the Filename without path?  What are you doing to detect that?  The textbox contents?

Comment: I am setting: TB_ReplacementFile.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)

Comment: @jsteffler Drop `GetFullPath()`. Per the documentation (see the comment in my answer), you don't need it.

Comment: make sure there isnt code in one of the events that changes the contents or use the awesome debugger in VS, set a breakpoint and hold the mouse over `openFileDialog1.FileName`

Comment: OK... so first, thanks for the help. Second... some days we are the windshield, and some days we are the bug... I was editing two similar buttons (names are similar) @justin... I did have to have the GetFullPath. It works perfect. I was just editing the wrong %^$@#@$ button. I read the same docs, so I know what it says. I see literally dozens of posts about this, but when I do as directed by the posts (or the documentation) it does not work. At any rate as soon as I realized my very dumb mistake It is working as expected. THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSDN documentation and numerous posts all over the place say all you need is openfiledialog.FileName. However this did not work for me, can't tell you why. What DID work is to use this:

```
TB_ReplacementFile.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName)
```

This works great, I get what I need. I cannot explain why I have to do this. Not sure how I can be the problem, but that must be the problem right?!

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: `openFileDialog1.FileName` returns the file name with the full path. You need `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` to "extract" only the path from the filename.

Answer (score 2):

The [FileName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the full path.

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").

```
If (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    TB_ReplacementFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName
End If
```

Comment: I tried this... same result... I just get the file name and nothing else

Comment: @jsteffler Uh... Is your TextBox doing any transforms on the text upon change? Are you assigning it as I've done above (directly), or applying some other methods to the return? The documentation is pretty clear, and I've used this frequently myself, so I don't see why it would be different. Perhaps just try a `MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName` on success to test.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this would resolve the issue you're having, or if it's simply just another way to handle it, but I prefer to check the DialogResult. I.E:

```
Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Z:\"

openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok Then
    Console.WriteLine(openFileDialog1.fileName)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked to get the directory or path
dim sDir as String  = System.IO.Path.**GetDirectoryName**(openfiledialog1.FileName.ToString)